# Is VBScript or JavaScript more handy for writing scripts for Enterprise Architect?

Tags: javascript, vbscript, automation, jscript, enterprise-architect

I did some complex data gathering in Enterprise Architect. Now I want to automatise this by writing a script.

Since I have to start from scratch I can freely choose which scripting language I will use. As [EA best supports scripting in JavaScript and VBScript](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/automation/the_scripter_window.html) it seems easiest to choose one of them.

**Is either:**

- **Microsoft VBScript or**
- **JavaScript / Microsoft JScript**

**a more handy choice for writing a new EA-Script?**

Like "Are there more good EA examples to built on for one of them?" or "Is either better supported by the EA Script Editor?"

---

*Note:*
*I am **not** looking for an answer to the question "Which one is better JavaScript or VBScript?" That is highly debatable.*

Comment: *Microsoft JScript* is Microsoft's implementation of JavaScript and only differs from that language by name.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I updated the question to match that fact.

Comment: Enterprise Architect will expose the very same [OLE Automation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_Automation) API (TypeLibrary) to each scripting environment. You can access the automation library also from other (even type-safe) languages like Delphi, C#. From the perspective of Enterprise Architect there is not difference and questions of form "which one is better Pearl or Google Dart" don't have a clear answer and as such are considered an [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) here

Comment: The aspect "which one is better VBScript or JavaScript?" was not my intend with the question. I'd be more interested in EA-specific aspects like "Are there more good EA examples to built on for one of them?" or "Is either better supported by the EA Script Editor?" and so on.

Comment: How could I reword my question to eliminate the "opinion-based" part of it? I really think that there are several aspect in this question that would allow objective as well as interesting answers. Can somebody make a suggestion for rewording to enhance these aspect or eliminate the "opinion based" aspect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both languages are indeed about equal in what they offer.

VBScript however has a slight advantage in that

- Most of the documentation in the EA help file is written with examples in VB, which resembles the syntax to be used in VBScript.
- It is easier to create an input dialog from VBScript then it is from JScript according to [this post](http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?num=1294601083/1#1) on the sparx forum

Answer (score 1):

In VBScript you have the possibility to use the Option Explicit when you declare your variables see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

The advantage is that you are forced to declare your variables i advance before you use them. You don't have this possibility in javascript. If you don't use this feature you risk creating new variables without our will because of typos eg.:

```
carname = "Volvo";
cartype = "truck";
....
carstring = carname + " " + cartupe
```

The variable carstring will have the value "Volvo " and not "Volvo truck", because the 'cartupe' is not initialized to any value.

On the other hand you can chose javascript because there is a larger userbase and more help to get, if you have troubles.

Comment: Actually you compare pears with apples here. One should take the language that he/she has used the most. Whether J or VB is best is not discussable. Both have pro and con. I myself would opt for a completely different language ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no difference in support of either language. Though I have no code insight and can only speculate Sparx uses 3rd party products in both cases and just presents its own API short hand (that is, objects like the repository are directly available).

So as I commented above your choice should be decided by your personal feelings against either language.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. As I'm a Java Developer my natural choice would be JavaScript. But I'm not averse to learning a new language, and this might be the oppurtunity for it. Due to this "my personal feelings towards the two languages are in equilibrium"-situation I'd like to make a fact based choice rather than a personal feelings-choice.